# Include subproject zip file with Maven Assembly Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My Maven project structure is :

```
+ parent
++ moduleA
++ moduleB
```

In moduleB, I use the assembly plugin to generate a first zip file. As expected, it generates a moduleB.zip file in moduleB/target/ directory :

```
<assembly>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <!-- ... -->
    </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Now in my parent module, I would like to generate another zip file, and include moduleB.zip file.

How can I do that? Should I use moduleSets? dependencySets? something else?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311308/including-artifiacts-from-pom-package-module-in-maven-assembly-plugin

Answer (score 0):

When you are in the parent project you cannot create an assembly that will embed its modules, but there are two solutions :

1. You can create a second assembly in the `moduleB` that will create the final assembly that you want and that will surely be different from the first one created, you just have to pay attention to the order of the `executions` in your plugin configuration
2. Or you can create a third module `moduleC` *(for example ^^)* that will have a dependency on `moduleB` (with `type` `zip` for example and a `classifier` that you can define in `moduleB`) and in which you will create your final assembly

You can find additional information here : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#module-binaries

Personally the solution I always use is the second one with a module dedicated to the final assembly.

Comment: Then please show us how it is possible to do it. I quote the documentation from the plugin (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/multimodule/module-binary-inclusion-simple.html) : Warning: Using the binaries section of a moduleSet definition involves some tricky considerations that are a result of the way Maven sorts and executes project builds within a multimodule context. Please read this FAQ entry if you decide to use them. Then read this part : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/faq.html#module-binaries

Comment: And also if you can give a working example, it would be nice.

Comment: You are right, in that the docs say that. But after many tests and posts readings, there are examples available that demonstrate that it is now possible. First of all, a mention to a more elaborated example: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/assemblies-sect-controlling-contents.html#assemblies-sect-modulesets-parent-pom.

Comment: This doc confirms indeed your linked info, but at the same time points to a bug that has been closed (as won't fix!?). In the bug there are posts suggesting to use `assembly:single` as a solution to the reported bug. Furthermore, it is very old (closed in 2006).

Comment: All in all, if you need a working example, you can change child1's package to jar in this project https://github.com/gallardo/SO/tree/master/SO-33999969

Comment: Thanks for those information, I'm going to try all this during the week-end :)

Comment: in any case, the docs for the maven assembly plugin are pretty confusing, and it seems there is in fact a consensus to assemble modules in a child module. I'd edit your post to only suggest to use any of the workarounds instead of asserting that it's not possible to create assemblies in the parent. But until I get an answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999969/can-assembly-aggregate-artifacts-with-modulesets-directive-from-modules-with-p), you could probe me wrong. For the same reason (uncertainty), I'm removing my fist (and probably too bold) comment.