# Including artifiacts from pom package module in maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

This is my current maven build module structure. Maven-assembly-plugin with assembly descriptors are used for the build. It works but I am not sure if this is the right way to do it. [Code here on GitHub.com](https://github.com/KiranMohan/maven-assembly-samples)

```
p-build-root (packaging:pom)
        |
        |---p-build-data
        |               (packaging:pom, builds data.tar)
        |
        |---p-build-scripts
        |               (packaging:pom, builds a scripts.tar)
        |
        |---p-build-final
        |               (packaging:pom, builds p.tar)
        |               (In p.tar, need to include data.tar and scripts.tar)
        |               (dependency:
        |                       p-build-data:type[tar.gz],
        |                       p-build-scripts:type[tar.gz]
        |               )
```

I also tried using moduleset but not sure how this really works. Infact p-build-final always builds first. I expected the submodules to build first.
Anyways does it make more sense to use this below structure than the above one?
Any samples projects? Or how to achieve the target?

```
p-build-final
    (packaging:pom, builds p.tar)
    (In p.tar, need to include data.tar and scripts.tar)
    |
    |---p-build-data 
    |       (packaging:pom, builds data.tar)
    |   
    |---p-build-scripts 
    |       (packaging:pom, builds a scripts.tar)
    |
```

Comment: what a pitty that this remains unanswerd :( ... Facing similar problem. Up to now, I found that moduleSet doesn't recourse into projects with pom packaging.

Comment: @Alberto - no answer yet :-(

Comment: I've dived a bit deeper into this problem: [Can assembly plugin in parent module aggregate binary artifacts of pom children...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999969/can-assembly-plugin-in-parent-module-aggregate-binary-artifacts-of-pom-children). At his point, I'm beginning to consider writing a bash-script to accomplish my goal.