# Can assembly plugin in parent module aggregate binary artifacts of pom children with `moduleSets`?

Tags: maven

In a multimodule project:

```
parent
  |- child1 (packaging:pom)
```

can `parent` aggregate artifacts generated by `child1`?

After more than two days testing and reading docs, I'm not sure if it isn't possible by design, by bug or by myself not finding the obvious.

Using:

```
$mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven-bin-3.0
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

Remarks:

- In the following examples, changing child1 packaging from `pom` to `jar` does work as expected!
- The current error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.6:single (build-module) on project parent: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive bundle: You must set at least one file. -> [Help 1]

- I'm attaching a second version of child1's pom, that doesn't work either, where I have set all jar packaging bindings not available for pom packaging modules, that is, it's effective poms for packaging=pom or packaging=jar are identical. This doesn't work either!

---

### Example code

(Complete code: https://github.com/gallardo/SO/tree/master/SO-33999969)

#### parent pom: /pom.xml

```xml
...
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>parent</name>

<modules>
    <module>child1</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/bundle.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <attach>false</attach>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-module</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>          
    </plugins>
</build>
```

#### child1 pom: child1/pom.xml

```xml
...
<artifactId>child1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>child1</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Assembly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/module.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-module</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>          
    </plugins>    
</build>
```

#### parent assembly: /src/assembly/bundle.xml

```xml
<assembly ... >
    <id>bundle</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>false</useAllReactorProjects>
            <includeSubModules>true</includeSubModules>

            <binaries>
                <attachmentClassifier>module</attachmentClassifier>
                <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
                <outputDirectory>my/output/directory</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

#### child1 assembly: src/assembly/module.xml

```xml
<assembly ...>
    <id>module</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <outputDirectory>module-${project.artifactId}/java</outputDirectory>
            <filtered>false</filtered>
        </fileSet>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
            <outputDirectory>module-${project.artifactId}/lib</outputDirectory>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
            </includes>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

</assembly>
```

#### child1 'extended' pom: /child1/pom.xml

(simulating `jar` packaging)

```xml
...
<artifactId>child1</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>child1</name>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!--
        These plugin settings are the plugin bindings that jar packaging
        configures for the jar packaging.
        If this project has packaging = pom, enabling them results in an
        effective pom identical to packaging = jar.
        -->            
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testResources</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Assembly -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/assembly/module.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-module</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>          
    </plugins>    
</build>
```

Comment: The parent cant cause it is executed first and so in result it does not work. If you like to have a distribution archive etc. you should create a separate module like `app-dist` which contains the definition and has dependencies on all the artifact you would like to package into to have the correct build order which is automatically predicted by Maven and the dependencies. See here: https://github.com/khmarbaise/javaee/

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks, but why does it work when children is of packaging jar? Furthermore, maven currently solves the correct reactor build order, namely child1, parent, so I'm a bit reluctant to accept the assertion 'the parent is executed first'.

Comment: so which version of Maven do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm also trying to avoid the need to explicit declare the modules I want to assemble: I find that too cumbersome and error prone. It defies the purpose of using an assembly using `moduleSets`. In my "real" multimodule project, I have a few modules that only assist the build and must not be included in the assembly. The rest of modules must be included. They are quite a few, and I keep on adding new ones. I don't want to keep a list of dependencies that I have to update whenever a new module is born.

Comment: @khmarbaise `mvn --version: Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)` (I have edited the post to reflect it)